# node mysql pulling results and changing them during logging

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am having an issue currently with node mysql.

My sql table has the following entries:

(id, steamid, name) value (1, 76561198124567784, name1)

I am using the following query:

```
setInterval(function () {
    var connection = mysql.createConnection(db_access);
    connection.connect(function(err){
      if(err){
        console.log('Error connecting to Db');
        return;
      }
    });

    var q = "SELECT * FROM tradeOfferPoll";

    connection.query(q, function (err, results) {
        if (err) throw err;

        if (results.length > 0) {
            console.log(results[0].steamid);
            console.log(results[0].name);
        }
    });
}, 5000);
```

so every 5 seconds this checks the database and when a row appears it tells me the two rows.

I've noticed that the name comes through correctly however the id comes through wrong. only 1 digit changes and its the last one.

76561198124567784

76561198124567780

Why is that last digit changing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is the `mysql` module is automatically casting the column's value to a JavaScript `Number`, which can only accurately represent an integer whose value is less than or equal to `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` (`9007199254740991`). Your `steamid` value is larger than this value, so precision is lost when the value is parsed and converted to a `Number`.

You can disable *all* automatic casting of values in the `mysql` module by setting `typeCast: false` in your connection config. You can also *just* target numbers by instead setting `supportBigNumbers: true, bigNumberStrings: true`.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a couple of solutions.

Comment: I used supportBigNumbers and bigNumberStrings and it worked. Thanks